# Bi-Directional Binding not work in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following HTML on my page

```
<div data-personselect="" data-ng-model="selectedPersonName" data-person="currentOwnership.Person" data-id="currentOwnership.PersonId"></div>
```

This is using a person directive that I have defined like this:

```
'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.directive('personselect', function (personDataService) {
        var link = function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.names = [];

            $scope.getNames = function (name) {
                return personDataService.FullNameSearch({ name: name, pageSize: 10 })
                    .then(function (sourceData) {
                        $scope.names = sourceData;
                        return sourceData;
                    }, function (error) {
                        config.logger.error(config.errorMessage("search"));
                    });
            };

            $scope.selectItem = function () {
                //$scope.$parent.$parent[$attr.person.split('.')[0]][$attr.person.split('.')[1]]
                $scope.person = findPerson($scope[$attr.ngModel]);
                $scope.id = $scope.person == undefined ? undefined : $scope.person.id;
            };

            function findPerson(itemToFind) {
                var item = _.find($scope.names, function (member) {
                    return member.name == itemToFind;
                });
                if (item == undefined) return undefined;
                return item;
            }

        };


        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                id: '=',
                person: '=',
                defaultName: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/people/personSelect.html',
            link: link
        };
    });
});
```

You can see at the bottom that I have defined an isolated scope, which contains 2 properties 1 for id and one for person.  This isolated scope is using = so it should be bidirectionally bound to the properties that are being set from the html on the page; currentOwnership.Person and currentOwnership.PersonId in my example.

Now when I select a person the $scope.selectItem method is being called and I'm setting the $scope.person and $scope.id properties correctly, but the currentOwnership.Person and currentOwnership.PersonId properties from the parent scope are not being changed.

What am I missing here

Comment: Try console.logging $scope, and $scope.$parent to see if you are updating local scope versions of your variables, or the correct parent scope variables.

Comment: I am updating the local scope variable $scope.person inside of the directives, but when I look at the parent it is not updating that.  It is actually the parent.parent that contains the variable that I'm trying to update because the html at the top is inside of another directive, that directives scope is just set to '='

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or jsfiddle @PaulCavacas! With it it will be more simple for us to help you asap.

Comment: Sure here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PWdYZ/15/).  There is a couple of alert boxes that you can uncomment and see that it is changing and setting the local scope variables, but the top level one is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the problem is with your parent scope, in the sense that it does not include the `currentOwnership.PersonId` item. In other words, you are binding the template scope properties with non-existing properties of your parent scope.

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWdYZ/16/) including the `currentOwnership.PersonId` property in the controller's scope and it looks like it works.